# Provide access to send, receive messages to Topic in Microsoft Service Bus for Windows Server without installing certificates

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, servicebus

To access Microsoft Service Bus Namespace and to send and listen messages on a particular topic, I have to import certificates on the client machine. The certificate can be used by the user who has access on that Namespace.

Is there a way where we do not need to install certificates on the client machine? I am accessing Service bus using client inside the domain.

Comment: Can you reference something saying why you need a cert?  Windows Azure Service Bus doesn't need a cert, and I believe the local Service Bus for Windows Server also does not need a cert because it ships with a simple Secure Token Service to be a stand in for ACS that the cloud based version uses.